How to check code in cloud is consistent with code in local
When I use local IDE to remote debug code which running in prod cloud, IDE can determine if the position can be debugged(I don't know how it works to determine if the code is consistent)
Now I have another feature to inject log into the application with my own agent, but I want to sure the code in my local IDE is consistent with the code running in prod cloud, Is there good way to realize it in Java? checksum? hash?
